# S3 Buckets - Access Denied exception for some objects, not all

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 services that are uploading documents A and B to my S3 bucket.

These services can GET document A from the S3 bucket, but when trying to download doc B, I get AccessDenied exception.

When I check the documents in S3, the value for 'Server-side encryption' is 'None' but for document B it says 'Access denied'... both documents are under the same bucket and been uploaded using similar Java code. I am completely clueless why 2 uploads are working differently when I am not specifying anything about encryption etc. Also, the bucket permissions are open to all public as of now.

Also note that from the console, I am not even able to OPEN or DOWNLOAD doc B, but works for doc A

Any tips would be appreciated highly.

Thanks

Comment: *"uploaded using similar Java code"* ...but not the same credentials, right?  Is it possible that the one you can't access was actually uploaded using credentials from a different AWS account?  What if you upload a test object to the bucket, yourself, from the console?  Are you then able to access that object?

Comment: Both services are deployed under the same EC2 and using the same credentials. When I upload a document manually, it acts like doc A i.e. can download/open it and the encryption shows disabled. 

Its only this case of doc B, where I am seeing 'Access Denied' in encryption. Wasted a day on this issue that initially seemed like something minor config :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, still don't quite know the root cause, but I created a new bucket from the scratch and that seems to be working fine. The bucket name that wasn't working was previously being used in some other AWS account, but even then doesn't make sense for it to be behaving unexpectedly with such a vague error. Anyway, if it helps anyone, just create a new bucket and save some time. :)